# Cropped title of item BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, navigationbar, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

When Using the design library `'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'` BottomNavigationView incorrectly displays item title with long text:

[image]
My layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".mvp.ui.activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It looks very strange because the exact same code when using the design library `com.android.support:design:27.1.1` generates a great result:

[image]

How is this possible? for the new version of the library I tried to use `labelVisibilityMode`,but this did not help.

`app:showAsAction="always"` does not work either. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

After update material library you need to use
`navigation_bar_item_large_label_view` instead of `R.id.largeLabel`

```
public void removePaddingFromNavigationItem() {
BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);

for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
    View activeLabel = item.findViewById(R.id.navigation_bar_item_large_label_view);
    if (activeLabel instanceof TextView) {
        activeLabel.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use this helper , it uses reflection to change BottomNavigationBar's TextView(s) properties!

```
public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {
    public static void refineBottomBar(Context context, BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);

                Field LargeText = item.getClass().getDeclaredField("mLargeLabel");
                LargeText.setAccessible(true);
                Field SmallText = item.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSmallLabel");
                SmallText.setAccessible(true);
                TextView SmallTextView =(TextView) SmallText.get(item);
                TextView LargeTextView =(TextView) LargeText.get(item);
                SmallTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                LargeTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                SmallTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                LargeTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                LargeTextView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                SmallTextView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to set margins to 0 using the layout params and test it

Comment: again a bad result ((

Answer (score 1):

This is because of inappropriate padding for the **active** child view,(maybe an issue) ,you could create a function like this:

```
public void removePaddingFromNavigationItem() {
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
        View activeLabel = item.findViewById(R.id.largeLabel);
        if (activeLabel instanceof TextView) {
            activeLabel.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

and call `removePaddingFromNavigationItem` method before the `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener`.

Comment: This is a great solution for my 5 inch display! But the problem remains for 4-inch displays.

Comment: Source: - https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/139